# What would 箆深い (のぶかい) mean?

Tags: words, usage, reading-comprehension, i-adjectives, semantics

While 深い (ふかい) means "profound; deep; dense", 箆 (へら, の), as a noun, means "spatula; arrow shaft" in japanese and, originally, "fine-toothed comb" in chinese.

This word is used adverbially in this sentence:

> 箆深く射された矢がなかった。

箆深く could mean something like "deep as an arrow" or "arrow-like deep", but would it not be redundant if it appears before 矢?

Answer (score 2):

> 「箆深{のぶか}く射{さ}された矢{や}がなかった。」

「箆{の}」, in this context, means a "**bamboo arrow shaft**".  There is indeed a 「竹」 ("bamboo") radical used at the top of the kanji.

「箆深{のぶか}し」 is an adjective which [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%AF%A6%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%97%E3%83%BB%E7%AE%86%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%97-354741) defines as:

> 矢が根元{ねもと}まで深くささっている。
>
> "(of an arrow) stuck through (an object)"

「箆深く」 is the 連用形 of 「箆深し」 functioning adverbially.

The arrow was not there to see.

> 箆深く could mean something like "deep as an arrow" or "arrow-like deep", but would it not be redundant if it appears before 矢?

I personally see no redundancy here as 「矢」 does not appear *directly* in the adjective 「箆深く」.

Comment: So, could I render this sentence just as "there was no arrow that deeply shined" or should "deeply" have another meaning?

Comment: @Daniel Does it really say 射された rather than 刺された. Is this another of this author's weirdnesses?

Comment: Yep, it says so. The book is from 1949, so maybe it wasn't that weird in modern literary japanese.